# Find all records with id that incuded in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and i would like to run this command to find all loads that are included in an array

```
@user_loads = Load.where(:user_id => params[:id])
```

but instead of `:user_id => params[:id]`

I want it to be something like this:

```
include? loadids
```

i have an array of load id's saved to loadids

loadids = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass in an array to where

```
loadids=[1,2,3,5,6,10]
Load.where(:id => loadids)
```

or

```
Load.where("id in (?)", loadids)
```

resulting query would be something like

```
select * from loads where user_id in (1,2,3,5,6,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of ID's you can use the find method and pass that array

```
Load.find(params[:id])
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding it should be like this:

```
@user_loads = Load.where(:id => loadids, :user_id => params[:id])
```